# How to adding navigation bar button having ionic-on/ ionic-off functionality

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to add star button on navigation bar and when user press on this, the button show selected icon and next time is press it show unselected.
I tried it by using ionic-on and ionic-off but I can't make it.

Comment: Have you tried with `ng-disabled` ? No idea if it will work or not, just an idea like that.

Comment: ok I try to think on it but I think its easy to set that type class on that button, But I don't how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The `icon-on` and `icon-off` attributes only apply to tabs I think. You can use `ng-class` like you see here. Based on the value of your `$scope.starred` property, it will show a star or the outline of a star.

```
<span class="icon" ng-class="{'ion-ios-star': starred, 'ion-ios-star-outline': !starred}"></span>
```