# How to make a On/Off button in Ionic AND execute a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

There is a nice solution here for [How to make a On/Off button in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462462/how-to-make-a-on-off-button-in-ionic)

Here's a demo from [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doOdqj)

and the code pasted here:

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

      $scope.someFunction = function(){

               alert('I am pressed')

        }

});
```

---

```
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Toggle button
    </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
          <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
          </head>
      <body class="padding" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <button class="button button-primary" ng-model="button" ng-click="button.clicked=!button.clicked" ng-class="button.clicked?'button-positive':'button-energized'">
          Confirm
        </button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My question is how to execute `someFunction()` on the same ng-click event of the Confirm button which could be like this `ng-click="someFunction() && button.clicked=!button.clicked"` ?

Comment: what is your `button` object? There is none shown in scope. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do

Comment: better to move all the logic and variables to scope but can use `;` as separator

Comment: The `;` really worked. But how to **move all the logic and variables to scope** ?

Comment: create a button object and just call function

Comment: Please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `;` separator, you could move all the logic into `someFunction()`, and set that function as the expression to the `ng-click` attribute:

```js
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.buttonOn = false;

$scope.someFunction = function() {
  $scope.buttonOn = (!$scope.buttonOn);
  alert('I am pressed');
}
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Toggle button
    </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
          <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
          </head>
      <body class="padding" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="someFunction()" ng-class="buttonOn?'button-positive':'button-energized'">
          Confirm
        </button>
      </body>
    </html>
```